# Jenkins war deployed on tomcat 9 . Not able to start the tomcat server after stop. showing killed message

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, centos

Jenkins (version: 2.121.2) war was deployed on Apache-tomcat(version: 9). It was working properly last few months.

Due to some memory error i stopped the tomcat server ( command i used : sh bin/shutdown.sh ). It was not stopped i Killed the process.

After that, i cleaned the logs, temp and work folders.

I am not able to start the server after that, while i am starting i am getting following exception.

```
[centos@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx apache-tomcat-9]$ sh bin/catalina.sh start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.

[centos@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx apache-tomcat-9]$ sh bin/catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Killed
```

Process not getting started. it shows killed.

where can i check the log ? how can i debug it ?

I have check Memory space also

```
[centos@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx apache-tomcat-9]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        1.3G        4.0G        392M        2.3G        5.6G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

[centos@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx apache-tomcat-9]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      200G   38G  163G  19% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  393M  3.5G  11% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           783M  4.0K  783M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1001
```

Could any one please help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: You can search for logs in `/opt/apache-tomcat-9/logs`

Comment: @RomeoNinov nothing printing in catalina.out file. i already checked.

Comment: You can set log to write debug information. And restart tomcat and check again

Comment: @RomeoNinov could you please help me , How can i configure debug in logging.properties file ?

Comment: In this file set records which end to `.level` to **FINEST**. For example "1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST"